# Kotlin/Multiplatform how to see stdout/stderr of tests on console?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

I tried setting the following for all the tasks having type `Test` as follows:

```kotlin
tasks.withType<Test> {
    testLogging {
        exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
        showStandardStreams = true
        showStackTraces = true
    }
}
```

But the setting only applies to the JVM, but not all the targets on Kolin/Multiplatform.

How to direct/enable the standard out and standard error streams to output in the console?

Only the exception name is printed in the console (not even the exception message):

```
> Task :keyboard:linuxX64Test FAILED

com.github.animeshz.keyboard.NativeKeyboardHandlerTest.Caps lock key should be toggled when KeyDown event is triggered FAILED
    kotlin.IllegalStateException

com.github.animeshz.keyboard.NativeKeyboardHandlerTest.Test send and receive event FAILED
    kotlin.IllegalStateException
```

I don't know how to debug this now, when I'm testing the library on multiple targets (on a VM) when I don't have (want to install) Intellij there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `testLogging` for each test task type as you are currently only defining it for JVM, something similar to this should work in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```
tasks {


        val jvmTest by getting(Test::class) {
            testLogging {
                events("PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED")
                exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
                showStandardStreams = true
                showStackTraces = true
            }
        }

        val linuxTest by getting(KotlinNativeTest::class) {

            testLogging {
                events("PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED")
                exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
                showStandardStreams = true
                showStackTraces = true
            }
        }

        val jsNodeTest by getting(KotlinJsTest::class) {
            testLogging {
                events("PASSED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED")
                exceptionFormat = TestExceptionFormat.FULL
                showStandardStreams = true
                showStackTraces = true
            }
        }


    

}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct direction, I did for all of them in once by `tasks.withType<AbstractTestTask> {...}`.